# Mysql: qcache_not_cached

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, query-cache

I am trying to understand if there is a way to get a hold of the queries that are not being cached by the mysql query_cache. I did try to see if there were any explicit references to "SQL_NOCACHE" on any of my queries, but none of them returned that string. And I still see a consistent increase in the queries that are not being cached. The percentage of those is around 5-10%, but I am trying to see if I can cache them up on memcache, if query cache doesn't cache them.

So is there a real way to log the queries that are not being cached?

Comment: Why don't you just increase your query_cache_size on the server and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way of doing this inside a procedure or "automated" from jdbc or similar. Neither have I ever seen it in any logs. But if you query your database using command line you could write a script that gets the  Qcache_hits before and after your query. If it increases the query used the cache, if it the same it didn't.

```
show status like 'Qcache_hits';
select * from table;
show status like 'Qcache_hits';
```

Comment: well I am doing that. It is getting a good amount of hits, and at the same time the Qcache_not_cached has been increasing. So I was trying to see, if they are not being cached on mysql, I'd cache them on memcache.

Comment: What does Qcache_free_memory say? Is the memory full? Then you could try to increase the memory. If not, 10% of the queries might very well be the best you can get. Remember that after each insert, update and delete the cache will be invalidated for some data and you would get a cache miss. Also some queries are un-cacheable, those that contains functions like now() or rand(). 
Generally I think it's a bad idea to add those to memcache instead but in some cases it can be ok. Like with now(), you could well cache that for a couple of seconds.